# How to add a read replica for azurerm_mssql_database using terraform in Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure, terraform

**read_replica_count -** The number of readonly secondary replicas associated with the database to which readonly application intent connections may be routed.

setting the above to 1 in `azurerm_mssql_database` doesn't seem to create any additional replicas.

`read_replica_count = 1`, was expecting to create a replica in azure.

Comment: Please provide actual TF code demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the below code which worked:

Here ***`create _mode is kept secondary`*** to create replicas and primary database must be created before that.

**Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "primary" {
  name         = "primarykadatabase"
  server_id    = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  create_mode  = "Default"     
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "read_replica" {
  name         = "read-replica"
  server_id    = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  create_mode  = "Secondary"
  read_replica_count = 1
  creation_source_database_id = azurerm_mssql_database.primary.id
    
  depends_on = [
  azurerm_mssql_database.primary
]
  
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
  name                = "examplekaavserver"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "eastus"
  administrator_login = "adminuser"
  administrator_login_password = "4-v3ry-53cr37-p455w0rd"
  version                      = "12.0"

  
}


output "sku" {
  value= azurerm_mssql_database.read_replica.sku_name
}
```

**Note:**

***Verify the SKU*** of your Azure SQL server , whether it supports read replicas. Some SKUs do not support read replicas, so if you are using one of these SKUs, the replica will not be created.

The sku used here is Standard: SO

Also check ***Resource group and location*** in your Terraform configuration are same as the resource group and location of the Azure SQL server and database you are trying to replicate.

In order to create a read replica, you must have at least ***one primary database*** created in the same server. Also, make sure that the server SKU you are using supports read replicas.

[image]

Replica created in Sql database:

[image]